# Typescript extend type if boolean type is true

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'd like to know if it's possible to extend a type depending on another type's value?

```
interface NavType {
    hideNav?: boolean
    dev?: boolean
}
```

I'd like to allow the use of `hideNav` only if the `dev` arg is false.

```
const Navbar: React.FC<NavType> = ({ children, hideNav, dev = false }) => (
    <nav>
        {!dev ? (
            <NavDefault hideNav={!!hideNav}>{children}</NavDefault>
        ) : (
            <NavDev>{children}</NavDev>
        )}
    </nav>
)
```

How can I use conditionals in this case?

```
// Should PASS
const navArgs1: NavType = {
    hideNav: undefined,
    dev: true
}

const navArgs2: NavType = {
    hideNav: true or false,
    dev: false
}

// Should NOT PASS
const navArgs3: NavType = {
    hideNav: true or false,
    dev: true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define 2 types and let the component properties be their union; in principle the following (shown as [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHJwG4CE4GcUDeAUMqcgCYQYBcyARgPYMA2EcIA3EQL5FGiRYiFABEq6DABUAngAcUEAB6QQ5XGkw58yYmQpVaYKAFcIXPQAtglCQH5ax1RBigI5Lr37ho8JGgZgYhgSMvLISipqGth4hCRklDTI8Mz45mRWNpi0jCxsnDx8MI4IYMAMIMkAFIq0QSFyKAA+-oHimKEQAJQ6fJ4wVQT6SUamyNxdXANDiYYmEAA0yJkQEg5OLiBu45NE08O0KfhLK2vIoygTU4MHyXCpl7v7s+fzJ9ar2a9jV0RAA) code):

```js
interface NavBase {
    dev: boolean;
}

interface DevNavType extends NavBase {
    dev: true;
    hideNav?: undefined;
}

interface NotDevNavType extends NavBase {
    dev: false;
    hideNav: boolean;
}

// This simulates your component
function f(x: DevNavType | NotDevNavType) {

}

f({ dev: true });                      // Works
f({ dev: true, hideNav: undefined });  // Also works
f({ dev: false, hideNav: true });      // Works too - for any boolean value of hideNav
f({ dev: false });                     // Compiler error
f({ dev: true, hideNav: true });       // Compiler error
```

Notes:

1. You don't really need the base interface, `NavBase`
2. You may want to define a type for the union, to keep the code clear: `type NavType = DevNavType | NotDevNavType`